# Wildcard support on package name in Spring AOP pointcut expression

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, pointcut

I'm trying to implement a logger aspect that can be applied across multiple packages in my application. It is a big spring web application having many modules. Each module has it's own controllers, services and DAOs. The pointcuts I define targets all the public methods on each classes within the packages. It's `public * com.abc.module1.controllers.*.*(..)` for the controllers,  `public * com.abc.module1.services.*.*(..)` for the services and `public * com.abc.module1.daos.*.*(..)` for the DAOs in module1. I've around 30 such modules. So the problem is, to cover all these modules I have to define pointcuts for each of them. All the modules follow the same package structure. Is there a way I can specify the the pointcut that can cover all `controllers`, `services` that are placed in different modules? Does spring AOP allows wild cards in package names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do recommend reading the [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php), e.g.

- the [formal definition of type patterns](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/quick-typePatterns.html),
- a [list of example type patterns](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#type-patterns).

Then you would not need to ask a question like this here.

Anyway, here is how you solve your problem (I am adding line breaks for better readability):

```java
execution(public * com.abc..controllers..*(..)) ||
execution(public * com.abc..services..*(..)) ||
execution(public * com.abc..daos..*(..))
```

Or alternatively:

```java
(
  within(com.abc..controllers..*) ||
  within(com.abc..services..*) ||
  within(com.abc..daos..*)
) &&
execution(public * *(..))
```

If you use Spring AOP instead of full-fledged AspectJ you can make it even simpler because Spring AOP basically only knows `execution()` and no other pointcuts like `call()`, constructor execution, `set()` / `get()` etc.

```java
within(com.abc..controllers..*) ||
within(com.abc..services..*) ||
within(com.abc..daos..*)
```

With JDK dynamic proxies (default when your components implement interfaces) this would only target public method calls anyway. With CGLIB proxies it would also target protected and package-private ones. BTW, you also need to upgrade your simple pointcut to one of the above, more explicit ones, if you ever migrate from Spring AOP to AspectJ later.

Comment: FYI, I just updated the answer, adding alternative examples and more background info.

Comment: I'm a newbie in AOP. It worked. Thanks a lot for the explanation and references.